# 'BLACK RIGHT TRIANGLE' unicode symbol

Tags: unicode, styles

I'm searching an unicode symbol just like this `◢ (U+25E2)` but 45° rotated. I found this `► (U+25BA)` and this `▶ (U+25B6)`, but both are not good for me. The rectangle/arrow has to be shorter.

Is there such a symbol of?

**UPDATE 2012-12-11:**

The font-type is Arial!

The Symbol I'm searching for looks like this:
[image: It's a button, and after the button-text there is a small green rectangle.]

But in this case it's a graphic.

Comment: Have no idea if there is such symbol, but just a question - why do you need it? Possibly there is some other way to get what you need?

Comment: The actual shape of the glyph depends entirely on which font you are looking at. This is not programming-related, anyway; voting to move to SU.

Comment: @tripleee: I dont think there is such a symbol at all. forget their orientations and if you look closely, you will see that the first figure is a `Right Isosceles Triangle`, the second one is an `Isosceles Triangle`and the third one is an `Equilateral Triangle` They are quite different Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: @FAngel: I added a image to illustrate. I need this symbol for links or buttons instead of graphics.

Comment: What is wrong with symbols you already have? Why it is so important to get shorter arrow? I do not think that Unicode will provide infinite number of "shorter" and "longer" symbols. Plus - what is wrong with image?

Comment: @FAngel: If there are no more unicode symbol like this, I must use those...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `▶ (U+25B6)`. There are no more unicode symbol like this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you `BLACK RIGHT POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE` - U+25B8.

See a full list at - [FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b8/index.htm)

// Edit

Further to the above, are you aware of the ability to rotate text in css.  You can do something like this to place the `◢ (U+25E2)` and rotate it.

With the following css

```
.icon-triangle {
   display:block;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);  
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=0.7071067811865475, M21=-0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=0.7071067811865475, M21=-0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
   font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
 }
```

and the html something like this

```
<div><span class="icon-triangle">&#9698;</span></div>
```

This will use the icon you require, but rotate it 45 degrees down, to produce the right facing arrow.

Comment: Here's how the character looks: ▸

Comment: this is a very wrong answer Kami...

Comment: Sorry Kami, that's not what I'm searching for.

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX I have updated the answer with a different approach.

Comment: @Kami: transform I want to avoid, thx